# How to access all ASP.NET Identity 2.0 PasswordValidator properties?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I set multiple properties on the PasswordValidator, but the only rule that is checked is password length.

```
        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
         // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new  PasswordValidator()
        {
            RequiredLength = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PasswordRequiredLength"]),
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PasswordRequireNonLetterOrDigit"]),
            RequireDigit = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PasswordRequireDigit"]),
            RequireLowercase = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PasswordRequireLowercase"]),
            RequireUppercase = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PasswordRequireUppercase"])
        };
```

This is pretty much copied from the ASP.NET Identity sample app except the values are from config instead of hard-coded.

When I view the definition of PasswordValidator() I see that these properties are all defined (and it compiles and runs of course).  However, I notice when I test changing a password that only the length causes validation error.  The AccountController had this code from the sample:

```
        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
```

To get a better look I added

```
    IdentityResult resultPassword = await UserManager.PasswordValidator.ValidateAsync(model.NewPassword);
if (resultPassword.Succeeded)
{
    IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
```

and I notice that userManager.PasswordValidator is of class MinimumLengthValidator, not the PasswordValidator I thought we started with.  Of course, this explains the behavior, but I am at a loss to determine how to

1. Correctly add the "full" PassordValidator to my userManager and/or
2. Access the properties of the PassordValidator (such as RequireDigit, RequireUppercase, etc.)

Note, I have attempted

```
PasswordValidator myPV = (PasswordValidator)UserManager.PasswordValidator;
```

which results in a Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.MinimumLengthValidator' to type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.PasswordValidator' error.

Best,
Scott

Comment: Are you getting the UserManager object from the Owin Context or are you instantiating a new one each time ? Check out the AccountController for right usage

Comment: @SuhasJoshi - Thanks for input.  Most of the code came from AccountContoller (moved about as this is a closed system so we have User\Create and Manage instead of Account\Register ChangePassword.  But, it did get us looking at the UserManager object and I think it is a problem with our Unity configuration.  I'll post a resolution if we can get that working...

Comment: Hi Scott. I have the some problem. Did you ever find a solution please?

Comment: @Liam - Because our app does not have user registration, we removed the password fields from the CreateUser form and wrote a password generator that applies the web.config rules.  However, I just retested (using the PasswordReset form) and it now sets model errors about characters, numbers etc. as well as length.  We have had a couple of version updates since my post (now on ASP.NET Identity 2.2.1 and OWIN 3.0.1) - try getting the latest NuGet packages.  Best, Scott